# How will I be able to complete the event in Tiny Death Star at my current rate?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I was wondering something. I've been playing as much as possible for the last couple of days, resulting in a turnover of almost 500 'medals' per day. At this rate I will not be able to complete the event before the time runs out. What am I doing wrong?

(I'm currently approx. 100 medals in to the first char, R2-Q5!)

Answer (score 2):

You actually get the 3 limited edition droids at once, meaning you don't have to get x medals for each droid. I just got mine :). And now for the last reward - Imperial Marches.

So you'll be able to get all rewards at your current rate... Maybe just barely!

Comment: AHA!
Well that explains quite a lot, reducing the total number of medals needed with 2400 ! Thanks a lot man - you saved my day there ;o)

Comment: @Han Young padawan, you are taking over my position as the leading TDS expert.  Well done!

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to play the game almost constantly and whenever you get a Bitizen in your elevator, send them down to any Imperial floor (or focus on one). Each Bitizen sent will reduce the assembling time by a minute. So the more you send, the faster you assemble Imperial goods.

I've personally been doing this (and so finding the need to charge my phone so frequent!!!). At the moment I'm already working towards what I believe to be the final reward, Imperial Marches (527/1725 collected).

Cheers and all the best. :)

Comment: Another tip is to always build the faster component between the two which yields the same service medals. For instance, Recon Droid and Armor Upgrade from Interogation both yields 2 service medals, but the former only needs 10 minutes while the latter 30 minutes. So if you build Armor Upgrade, you will only reap 3 service medals in 30 minutes but building Recon Droids will theoretically net you 6 medals. Having said that, I tend to build the longer building component if it gives me more medals, like 4 medals for 50 minutes instead of 3 medals for 30 minutes for example.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably correct that under normal circumstances you may not have enough time to complete the event.  I don't know if you began it late, or you are behind for another reason.

But, luckily, there is a mechanism in the game to fix this problem.  You can spend Imperial Bux to speed up production of the items.  I believe the cost is 2 Bux for nearly every item.  If you spend Bux to complete the items faster, you could potentially get two to three days' worth done within one day.  (In fact, depending on your stockpile of Bux, you could do the whole thing in one sitting!)

Comment: I began when there was 10 days left. I don't know if that is late? It was the same day as my device updated the app.
With 230 bux that is 115 'free' products of 5 medals each => nowhere near enough for me to finish the event. God dammit...

Comment: I'm not sure why you are behind schedule.  Are you staying on top of the building of each item?   You might need to sit there and get them immediately as they're built.  Also, you have the option of spending real $ and buying more Bux.  (Perhaps, this was the original intent of the devs?)

Comment: As said, I entered with 10 days left. How long was/is the event?

Comment: I believe that you began this right at the beginning.  Again, I'm not sure why it's not running on schedule for you.  I assume that you have all of the Imperial levels built, etc?

Comment: Yes - 16 imperial levels. You REALLY need to do this tight in order to complete it imo. But then again, it seems I just have to 'get it together' :o)

Comment: There are now 17 imperial levels.  I haven't yet completed construction on Blaster Repair, but I presume when it is done you will be able to make stock and earn medals like the other levels.  And you can hurry many items along for a single bux, earning you 3 medals, so 230 bux gets you hundreds of medals.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to make up ground is with Interrogation - you can deliver 10 bitizens to the level every ~2 minutes [easiest if you locate it immediately below "Assignments"], so you're getting 60 medals/hour just from this floor.

My problem is that I only had 5 Imperial levels when this started...so I'm only getting about ~35/hour when I'm playing the game hard.  That means freakin' 100/hour TOPS and some 48 more hours of playing solid...that's not worth it :(  I'll have a few more levels by the time the event is up.  Hopefully Imperial Marches will be available for building later.

Any other thoughts?

Comment: The format of Arquade is Q&A and not an fourm so adding something like "Any other thoughts?" at the end of your answer is not really appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will be OK to complete the event.

Here is another tip to help out on top of all the other tips mentioned by others.

Don't ever spend 2 BUX to complete an imperial item!

The cost in BUX to complete an imperial item is based on the number of hours it takes to complete.  0-60 minutes = 1 BUX; 61 - 110 = 2 BUX.

Wait for the time to drop beneath an hour and then spend only a single BUX to complete the item and earn the medals.  There are items that yield 4 medals and take 1 hour and 20 minutes to complete.

This can yield a very consistent 4 medals for every one BUX spent.

Good Luck!